Redirect the Output of a Function to a Variable
I need to redirect the output of a function to a variable, to be called later.  I don't want the function output to show, except to the variable.  Here is my code:
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

char str[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
int length;
unsigned long int hxrnd()
{
  while(length--)
  {
    putchar(str[rand() % 16]);
    srand(rand());
  }
}
int main(void)
{
  printf ("\n======================\n Simple Psuedo Random\n   Hex Key Generator\n======================\n");
  srand((unsigned int) time(0) + getpid());
  length = 16;
  int x = hxrnd();
  printf("\n%d\n", x);
  length = 10;
  int y = hxrnd();
  printf("\n%d\n===================\n\n", y);
  return 0;
}

As it is, the output of the function shows and the variable returns 0.  As you can tell, I don't know much about programming.

Only call srand once in your program.And because your function doesn't actually have an explicit return statement, the values of x and y will be indeterminate. Also don't use global variables to pass data to functions, pass actual arguments.

And instead of printing output, which is non-trivial (but possible) to catch in your code, why not have it output to a string? Then the calling function can decide if it wants to print that string, or do something else with it.

First of all, you are trying to assign the return value of  hxrnd() to x and y, but there is no return statement in hxrnd().  Also, putchar writes a character to stdout.  So the output of functions shows and variable returns 0.

FAQ: srand() — why call it only once?

I'm clearly in over my head.  You all have given me a lot to digest.  I thank you all for your advice and answers.  I guess I should really take a course in C programming first.

Well, you have a lot wrong, but let's take it one by one.

Your hxrnd() has no return statement -- so it cannot return anything to assign to x or y.

You should only call srand() once, in main() before the first use of rand().

You attempt to create a random hex-string from str[], but fail to save the characters in any buffer in hxrnd() or fail to keep a running total of what the final hex-value would be.

Your code will not be portable to systems where unsigned long is 4-bytes (like x86), consider using unsigned long long and strtoull() -- up to you.

(avoid the use of global variables, pass parameters as needed to your functions)


If I understand your goal, you can fix hxrnd() by building a character string with your random hex characters and then call strtoul() to convert the random string to a value for return. (you should also validate the conversion by strtoul() -- that I leave to you).
Putting all the pieces together, you could do something similar to the following. Note a VLA is used as the buffer, but you can user a plain old array by declaring the array long enough to hold your max number of character +1 for the nul-terminating character.
That said, you could do something like:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>

#define BASE    16      /* if you need a constant, #define one or more */

unsigned long int hxrnd (const char *str, size_t len)
{
  char buffer[len * 2];                 /* variable length array */
  int index = 0;                        /* index to fill in buffer */
  
  while (len--)                         /* loop length times */
  {
    int c = str[rand() % BASE];         /* get char from string */
    while (index == 0 && c == 0) {      /* avoid leading 0 */
      c = str[rand() % BASE];
    }
    buffer[index] = c;                  /* save char in buffer at index */ 
    putchar(buffer[index]);             /* output your char (optional) */
    index += 1;                         /* increment index */
  }
  putchar ('\n');                       /* tidy up with newline */
  
  buffer[index] = 0;                    /* nul-terminate buffer */
  
  return strtoul (buffer, NULL, BASE);  /* convert to base-16 unsigned and return */
}

int main (void)
{
  char str[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";      /* avoid globals, pass parameters */
  size_t length = strlen (str);         /* use strlen() for string length */
  unsigned long x = 0,                  /* initialize all variables */
                y = 0;
  srand((unsigned int) time(0) + getpid());   /* call srand() once */
  
  printf (
    "\n"
    "======================\n"
    " Simple Psuedo Random\n"
    "   Hex Key Generator\n"
    "======================\n"
  );
  
  x = hxrnd (str, length);              /* strtoul() validation omitted */
  printf("\nx: %lu\n\n", x);
  
  length = 10;
  y = hxrnd (str, length);              /* strtoul() validation omitted */
  printf(
    "\n"
    "y: %lu\n"
    "===================\n"
    "\n", 
    y
  );
}

(note: the test for index == 0 && c == 0 to protect against the first hex-char being randomly chosen as 0)
Most importantly, learn to compile with warnings enabled, and do not accept code until it compiles without warning. To enable warnings add -Wall -Wextra -pedantic to your gcc/clang compile string (also consider adding -Wshadow to warn on shadowed variables and -Werror to treat warnings as errors). For VS (cl.exe on windows), use /W3. All other compilers will have similar options. Read and understand each warning -- then go fix it. The warnings will identify any problems, and the exact line on which they occur. You can learn a lot by listening to what your compiler is telling you.
Example Use/Output
Compile with gcc:
With your source in randhexstr.c
gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wshadow -Werror -std=c11 -Ofast -o randhexstr randhexstr.c

(omit -Ofast optimization and add -g to generate debug symbols for debugging)
Sample Output
$ ./randhexstr

======================
 Simple Psuedo Random
   Hex Key Generator
======================
BB61D5D9C37E6A74

x: 13502308289097919092

B2A61B5621

y: 767290988065
===================

Read the comments included in the code and let me know if you have further questions.

I assume that you provided an example for the more complex question about storing output into a variable and try to answer on that generic level.
If you want to store the result of the function for later, find an efficient way to store it. For that I recommend to condense to the information core of the output, separated from the representation fluff.
The example function you show has the informational core of a sequence of numbers of length length.
Side issues of your code I will not discuss, I will just name those which struck me (and others in comments):
Call srand() only once, call srand before rand(), make length a parameter instead of a global, if your prototype says that your function returns an integer then do so, for real randomness use something else.
For storing the information core of the function when it is called:

use an array or a memory region of size length
because the function gets the length as parameter, it cannot use an array (which are of fixed size in C)
either provide an array of suitable size to the function, which in the example you can, because outside of the function the length is fixed
(C does have variable length arrays, which could be used inside the function as a local variable, but they are not suitable if you want to hand the content over back to the caller of the function)
or create a dynamic memory area of suitable size (look up malloc())
give the start address of the array of allocated memory to the function
inside the function fill the information into the memory/array
I do not see a need for the function to have a return value, the returned information is found where the parameter address points to
you could use an additional return value to e.g. signal success or failure of whatever operation was done, if it can fail, then react in the calling function

Then, when you later want to use/print the output of the function:

use the information core from where you had it stored when calling the function
add the representation fluff

I.e. read the stored numbers from the array and turn it into a string to output.
Gist of it:

one function with rand() calls and the % operator inside a loop, storing to the memory
one function wiht the putchar() in a loop for representing to output

This concept is more generic than the output of random hex strings, which seems to be your goal in the example.

I addedd a note on VLAs after reading  the answer by ,@DavidC.Rankin, which I do not contradict in my differently approached answer. Thanks.
